# How to get field from a form in jquery

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
            <form id="searchForm" action="search" method="post">
                <input id="query" name="query" type="text" value="Find Friends"/>
                <input id="requestType" name="type" type="hidden" value="normal"/>
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search"/>
            </form>
```

Javascript

```
  var form = $('#searchForm');
```

Now for some reason I want to get the value of the field with id `query` from the form Object.
How will i do this?

i have tried `form.query` but it's undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#searchForm').find('#query').val();
```

If you knew it was always a first descendant you could use `.children` instead of `.find`.

Comment: I get it now thank you so much. and don't worry much about the down votes, i get them so much almost on any question i post. thing is that people don't realize that we are not all at the same level- one man's piece of cake is another mans mountain to climb. am so used to down votes i no longer aspire to get many up votes here am okay if after all votes have been cast i get the answer i was looking for.

Comment: @qualebs so switch `#searchForm` with `form`

Comment: @qualebs dont lose hope, you'l get there in the end! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using `.find()` on your form object:

```
console.log( form.find('#query').val() );
```